# Sort matrix keep colnames

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I did a regression and coerced all the estimated coefficients in beta.form. R tells me it is a matrix with dim(1,161). I would like to sort the coefficients in increasing manner.

My code:

```
beta.form <- reg.form$coefficients
beta.ranked <- sort(beta.form, decreasing=FALSE)
```

[image]

My problem: I would like to keep the names of the stocks. But beta.ranked returns me only the sorted values. Which is good already, but I need to know which value belongs to which stock.

If anyone could tell me how to sort while keeping colnames, I would appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it!
First I converted the output from the regression into a data.frame and then sorted it. The names and values are presented together.

The mistake I made was that I coerced the data into a vector and the structure of 1x161 was lost.

Solved!